# IOS 12 Xcode 10 _NSJSONRoundTrippingNumber JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, iphone, nsjsonserialization

I just installed Xcode 10 and I'm getting <_NSJSONRoundTrippingNumber: 0x6000026be5c0> in the response array in simulators but it's working fine in actual devices. Below is the code:

```
_m_programArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:retriveData options:-1 error:&err];
```

In _m_programArray I've some NSDictionaries, in these NSDictionaries I've some key value pairs including "notificationCount", whose value now showing "<_NSJSONRoundTrippingNumber: 0x6000026be5c0>". Now I don't know what is this and why it's coming and from where it's coming. Whereas the same code is still working fine in Xcode 9 and its simulators. Is it related to Xcode or Mac OS Mojave? How to Fix it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd tend to says that's a `NSNumber` internal class of Apple, so treat it as a `NSNumber`.

Comment: You are correct it works when I use NSNumber but I don't understand why it's happening now, not before. Thanks BTW.

Comment: Don't worry about internal Apple's classes. There are plenty of NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSData and their mutable versions, it's for internal optimization (for instance, array with only one object), etc.